# Spring Transactional Timeout for transaction with multiple queries

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I work on some old application which use both @Transactional along with old XML transaction.

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with 'get' are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="*" timeout=1500/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Now, I have a method which is supposed to fall in the AOP config as below:

```
<aop:config>
<aop:pointcut id="userServiceOperation" expression="execution(* x.y.service.UserService.*(..))"/>
<aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>
```

What it means is that all methods in UserService are now using txAdvice. I have a method within that service called:

```
createUserAndItsData()
```

This method will use the `txAdvice` i.e it will have Transaction with default config and `timeout = 1500s`.

Now within this method I have another method:

```
createUserSecrets()
```

This method now have `@Transactional` annotation. Within this I have multiple methods:

```
createUserAffairs() / createUserHistoryChats() / createUserHiddenPictures()
```

These method, each run some SQL. Here are my questions:

1. What configuration will `@Transaction` use? Is the `TransactionManager` autowired for these?
2. If I call method `createUserAndItsData()`, its time starts with 1500 timeout. Now methods inside `@Transactional` i.e `createUserAffairs() / createUserHistoryChats() / createUserHiddenPictures()` are called that take 800s 800s 800s.

Considering defaults to be Propagation. Required, will above timeout?

Additional Info:

I have same case as above: The method under `txAdvice` took 1500+s but didn't time out. Individual methods under `@Transaction` took < 1500s so they weren't supposed to timeout. On killing any session under `@Transactional`, completed Parent method under `txAdvice` got rolled back.